# If statement within an if statement in python for chess game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build some python script that can outline the moves available in a game of chess if someone started at x position. My code currently is as follows:

```
import argparse, json

chessBoard = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] for i in range(8)]

chess_map_from_alpha_to_index = {
    "b" : 0,
    "c" : 1,
    "d" : 2,
    "e" : 3,
    "f" : 4,
    "g" : 5,
    "h" : 6,
    "i" : 7
}

chess_map_from_index_to_alpha = {
    0: "b",
    1: "c",
    2: "d",
    3: "e",
    4: "f",
    5: "g",
    6: "h",
    7: "i"
}


def getRookMoves(pos, chessBoard):
    column, row = list(pos.strip().lower())
    row = int(row) - 1
    column = chess_map_from_alpha_to_index[column]
    i,j = row, column
    solutionMoves = []

    # Compute the moves in Rank
    for j in xrange(8):
        if j != column:
            solutionMoves.append((row, j))

    # Compute the moves in File
    for i in xrange(8):
        if i != row:
           solutionMoves.append((i, column))

    solutionMoves = ["".join([chess_map_from_index_to_alpha[i[1]], str(i[0] + 1)]) for i in solutionMoves]
    solutionMoves.sort()
    return solutionMoves

def getKnightMoves(pos, chessBoard):
    """ A function that returns the all possible moves
        of a knight stood on a given position
    """
    column, row = list(pos.strip().lower())
    row = int(row) - 1
    column = chess_map_from_alpha_to_index[column]
    i,j = row, column
    solutionMoves = []

    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 6][j + 1]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 6, j + 1])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 3][j + 2]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 3, j + 2])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 5][j + 3]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 5, j + 3])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 7][j + 4]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 7, j + 4])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 1][j + 5]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 1, j + 5])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 4][j + 6]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 4, j + 6])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i - 2][j + 7]
        solutionMoves.append([i - 2, j + 7])
    except:
        pass
    # Filter all negative values
    temp = [i for i in solutionMoves if i[0] >=0 and i[1] >=0]
    allPossibleMoves = ["".join([chess_map_from_index_to_alpha[i[1]], str(i[0] + 1)]) for i in temp]
    allPossibleMoves.sort()
    return allPossibleMoves

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--piece", help="chess piece name: ex- rook, knight, pawn etc")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--location", help="chess notation string: ex- E4, D6 etc")
args = parser.parse_args()

piece = args.piece.strip().lower()
location = args.location.strip()
# According to the type of piece adjust function
if (piece == "rook"):
    print (json.dumps({"piece":piece,
                      "current_location": location,
                      "moves": getRookMoves(location, chessBoard)}))
elif (piece == "knight"):
    print (json.dumps({"piece":piece,
                      "current_location": location,
                      "moves": getKnightMoves(location, chessBoard)}))
```

However ideally, I'd like to keep the if elif json.dumps at the end but modify the `try:
            temp = chessBoard[i - 5][j + 3]
            solutionMoves.append([i - 5, j + 3])
        except:
            pass`

section so this becomes an if statement as well. Therefore if a person types in python main.py -p "knight" -l "b8" then the code reads the `            temp = chessBoard[i - 5][j + 3]
            solutionMoves.append([i - 5, j + 3])
        except:
            pass``

relating to b8 as a location and outputs an answer based on it.

Hopefully that makes sense. Grateful for any help that can be given here.

Comment: Per your comment below, I think you should edit your question to reflect what you are really asking. My answer simplified the `getKnightMoves` function but it sounds like you are hoping for a way to simplify the whole thing. Is that correct?

Comment: I updated the second part of my answer to use the correct list of relative moves

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the `list index out of range` exception to trigger your try code. If you take a step back and think of why that exception is thrown you can re-work it into the desired if statement. That exception occurs because one of you indexes is larger than the list in your chess board. Your chess board in either direction is 8 items so you can just check against both 0 and 8:

```
if 0 <= i-3 < 8 and 0 <= j+2 < 8:
    solutionMoves.append([i - 3, j + 2])
```

The reason you had to have the extra negative filter before was a negative value is a valid index value for a list. You can get rid of those right away though.

You may want to consider creating a list of all of the cases you are checking (e.g. (-6,1), (-3,2), etc.) and embedding it the if check in a for loop to reduce the code duplication. Something like this:

```
# possible_moves are moves relative to current location
possible_moves = [(2, -1), (2, 1), (-1, 2), (1, 2), (-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (1, -2)]
for move in possible_moves:
    new_loc = (i + move[0], j + move[1])
    if 0 <= new_loc[0] < 8 and 0 <= new_loc[1] < 8:
        solutionMoves.append(new_loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just checking that the move dosen't take you off the board? You could do that with something like:

```
rf = i - 6
cf = j + 1
if 0 <= rf < 8 and 0 <= cf < 8:
     solutionMoves.append((rf, cf))
```

Although I may be missing something, You may want to look at this:
[How do I generate all of a knight's moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372622/how-do-i-generate-all-of-a-knights-moves)

Comment: Thanks both for your quick response. I am not sure if I was clear originally so thought I'd explain further. Ideally, I'd like a scenario whereby I can say okay a piece (assume knight here for ease) is in B8 then do x moves, if in B7 do y moves (completely separate moves). My thinking was it could be done as an if statement so if location = b8 return x moves, elif location = b2 return y moves, etc, etc. But each return is independent of the last so b8 would have a list of possible moves that would be different from b2, etc, etc